# Android Studio GIT check-out loses module

Tags: git, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 0.89 fine and have added support for GIT on cloudforge.  All looks to be working perfectly as I can commit and push and in cloudforge I can see the commits and far as I can see it is all there.

BUT if I check out the main branch (which is the only branch currently), it imports OK, but when Android Studio opens it I get the following error message:

Would you like to remove the VCS root '/.../.../..... for the removed module 'ZIPGM28OCT2014'?

If I say yes it opens with a Framework missing and asks you to configure and no modules are visible.  What I ever I do here does not matter there is no module to be able to build.

If I say no - I then I can see the module but it has red cross against it and when I build there is not module.  If you go to project>structure you see the information in the sreen shot.

I have gone around in circles with this and not getting anywhere.  I have tried most things I have found on stack overflow and else where but without any luck.  There some info on gitignore, which I do not have, but not sure why that should effect the loss of a module.

If I just copy the whole directory on this mac or on another and open it in Android Studio is works perfectly!

Any help or pointers on what I am doing wrong would be very much appreciated. As love Android Studio and from what I have seen from GIT it is great, I just can not get the two working together.

[image: VCS Error message]

[image: Project Structure]

If I am missing anything that would help - please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

it's work in my case

Answer (score 2):

OK - so I managed to get this working by checking out in Android Studio and then deleting it from my recent list of projects.  Then importing the project again by finding the directory created.  Once imported like this the project worked perfectly.

I assume there is an issue with checking out and rebuilding or it not doing the same as a Android Studio project import.

If anyone has a better way of doing this please do share as seems like a bit of a pain, but at least it is working now! BTW the way I have previously tried cleaning, making, rebuilding the project after checkout without any luck.

Comment: I just had to close and reopen.  I assume AndroidStudio was confused due to previous gradle errors (even after I resolved them).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem during switching between branches.
so first of all I commited the "./idea/gradle.xml" file that contains below line.

```
<option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/yourModuleName" />
       </set>
     </option>
     <option name="resolveModulePerSourceSet" value="false" />
   </GradleProjectSettings>
```

Then File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

It worked for me.